# PHP Codeigniter - How to set value to create database by option select

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I try to make a shipping method using [Rajaongkir API](http://rajaongkir.com), but I need to add some data to my database that contain the shipping cost  `<?php echo $data['rajaongkir']['results'][$k]['costs'][$l]['cost'][0]['value'] ?>`
but, it is always show an"0" in my database

this is my view

```
<?php echo form_open('orders/proceed'); ?>
     <select class="form-control">
            <option name="ongkir" selected="" disabled="">Pilih Layanan</option>
            <?php
             for ($l=0; $l < count($data['rajaongkir']['results'][$k]['costs']); $l++) { 
                ?> 

                <?php echo "<option value='".$data['rajaongkir']['results'][$k]['costs'][$l]['cost'][0]['value']."'>" ?>
                Layanan <?php echo $data['rajaongkir']['results'][$k]['costs'][$l]['service'] ?> |
                <?php echo $data['rajaongkir']['results'][$k]['costs'][$l]['cost'][0]['etd'] ?> Hari | Rp. 
                <?php echo $data['rajaongkir']['results'][$k]['costs'][$l]['cost'][0]['value'] ?>
                <?php "</option>"; ?>

            <?php
            }
            ?>

    </select>
```

and this is the controller

```
$carts = $this->cart->contents();
            $ongkir = $this->input->post('ongkir');

            foreach ($carts as $item) {
                $product = $this->Product->getProductByCode($item['id']);
                $detail['code'] = $item['id'];
                $detail['name'] = $item['name'];
                $detail['price'] = $item['price'];
                $detail['qty'] = $item['qty'];
                $detail['discount_percent'] = $item['options']['discount_percent'];
                $detail['net_price'] = $product['net_price'];
                $detail['weight'] = $item['options']['weight']; 
                $detail['order_id'] = $orderId;
                $detail['ongkir'] = $ongkir;

                $this->Order_detail->create($detail);
            }
```

this is the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

I cannot add the shipping cost to my value.
How to resolve it and and those shipping cost value to my database?

Comment: The field in your database, whats the datatype? Is the datatype you are trying to add the same?

Comment: yes, it's the same